# Making a database for a auto-part company in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a database for an auto parts company. I have made a few tables containing the car makes, models and series.

Here are the list of table made so far:

```
TABLE: make
 - make_id
 - name

TABLE: model
 - model_id
 - make_id
 - name

TABLE: series
 - series_id
 - model_id
 - name

TABLE: year
 - year_id
 - series_id
 - year_range
```

Now in the **year** table I want to add a field called **year range**, which will include the range of years for e.g: '2000 to 2010' for a series. So that when using select queries I list a year included in that range and it display the model and the series of that car.
I want to add a range rather than adding 10 entries from years 2000 to 2010 for the same series.
Is there a way I can achieve that ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a database ... so why are you concerned about another 10 entries? This smells of Premature Optimization. Unless you have already built a significant DB (i.e. 1,000,000 rows or more) and are having performance problems, then this is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy way would be to add 2 fields:

```
TABLE: year
 - year_id
 - series_id
 - year_start
 - year_end
```

and then you could look for series on, let's say 2008 doing:

```
SELECT * FROM
make
INNER JOIN model ON make.make_id = model.model_id
INNER JOIN series ON series.model_id = model.model_id
INNER JOIN year ON year.series_id = series.series_id
WHERE year_start <= '2008' AND year_end >= '2008'
```

Comment: I will be connecting the database to an online form, where users can just choose the year and it shows all the models, series in the year. Is this the best way of doing that ?

Comment: Works fine. It shows the years between the range. Thanks for you help !